# Установка драйвера postgresql на freebsd

Tags: postgresql, tomcat, freebsd

После установки программы были ошибки связанные с отсутствием драйвера postresql в папке tomcat.

Как установить драйвер posgresql на удаленный сервер с freebsd и в какую папку tomcat положить драйвер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Скачать jar-файл](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html) и положить в /usr/local/apache-tomcat-X.X/lib

Comment: Спасибо, но уже сделал)